# Может ли now() вернуть одинаковое время в разных транзакциях?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Вобщем может ли now() вернуть одинаковое время в разных транзакциях? (часы обратно переводить никто не будет) [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Akina, ну как я понял он будет одинаковым внутри транзакции, мало ли

Comment: @Akina прикрепил скрин)

Comment: Сорри, почему-то решил, что речь о MySQL. В PostgreSQL - да, все вызовы NOW() внутри транзакции вернут одно и то же значение. А в разных транзакциях - в зависимости от точности, но на максимуме точности - разное. При дефолтной точности в микросекунду получить одинаковое значение в разных транзакциях - считай без шансов.

Comment: Пишут, что разные транзакции могут иметь одинаковое время старта https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442408/does-postgresql-guarantee-unique-timestamps/3442489#3442489

Answer (score 2):

Да, может.

Разные тразакции могут быть запущены на разных ядрах процесора. Время для всех ядер процессора идёт одинаково. Так что, при такой ситуации, две транзакции начнутся однновременно.

Другой вопрос - вероятность такой ситуации. Конечно, она маловероятна. Но, когда кто то хочет искусственно вызывать коллизию - он может быть весьма настройчив.

Если Вам нужен ключ, независимый от времени - лучше использовать GUID.

Если нужно "выстроить транзакции в очередь по порядку" - можно использовать время, а потом положиться на стабильность мироздания :-) Но тогда может быть неопределенный результат - как награда за многопоточность